# Git init дублирует файлы с пометкой нижним тире, почему и для чего?

Tags: файлы, git, init

Ситуация при команде git init в папке с файлами дублируются все файлы с добавлением нижнего тире.
Пример до команды есть файлы help.txt, progress.txt -> после команды Git init -> в каталоге появляются добавочные файлы _help.txt, _progress.txt.

Почему так происходит, не могу найти информацию - Это ошибка или таковы настройки Git?

Comment: шота это глюк какой-то. такого не должно быть

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62387243/6104996  скорее всего проблема вот тут   .... и https://stackoverflow.com/a/59557443/6104996